# How to find the physical address of interrupts in interrupt vector table?

Tags: x86-16, microprocessors

How do i calculate the physical address of any given interrupt (INT22H or INT15H for instance) in the interrupt vector table for 8086 microprocessor?

Comment: Did you read documentation of x86? Are you in 16 bits, 32 bits or 64 bits mode? See also http://osdev.org/ & https://sites.google.com/site/masumzh/articles/x86-architecture-basics/interrupts-faults-and-traps but your question is too broad and off-topic (lacking some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: i'm in 16 bits mode.

Comment: In real mode (16 bit mode), the interrupts start at hex 0000:0000 in memory, taking 4 bytes each, so INT 15H would be a far pointer at hex 0000:0054. You can use INT 21h, AH = 35H to get a vector and AH = 25H to set a vector. See [wiki info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_API#DOS_INT_21h_services) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...calculate the physical address of any given interrupt (INT22H or INT15H for instance) in the interrupt vector table...

- Physical address where the `int 15h` instruction finds the far pointer that it should `call`.
  This is an offset **within** the Interrupt Vector Table, and so gives a physical address aka linear address from the list {0,4,8,12, ... , 1016,1020}.
  Since each vector is 4 bytes long, all it takes is multiplying the interrupt number by 4.

  ```
  mov  ax,0415h                  ;AL=Interrupt number, AH=4
  mul  ah                        ; -> Product in AX
  cwd                            ;(*) -> Result in DX:AX=[0,1023]
  ```

  (*) I like all my linear addresses expressed as DX:AX. That's why I used the seemingly unnecessary `cwd` instruction.
- Physical address where `int 15h` ultimately gets handled.
  This can be anywhere in the 1MB memory. (On [8086](/questions/tagged/8086) there's no memory beyond 1MB).
  Each 4 byte vector consists of an offset word followed by a segment word. The order is important.
  The linear address is calculated from multiplying the segment value by 16 and adding the offset value.

  ```
  mov  ax,16
  mul  word ptr [0015h * 4 + 2]  ;Segment in high word -> Product in DX:AX
  add  ax, [0015h * 4]           ;Offset in low word
  adc  dx, 0                     ; -> Result in DX:AX=[0,1048575]
  ```